# MAAS - logging into nodes after deploy

Tags: maas

I have MAAS working in my home and it is brilliant. I followed this guide, https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/03/06/maas-for-the-home, just not using lxd.

I need to know how to log in to nodes after a deploy. Thanks!

Is there a way I can set up ssh and users on every deployed box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) ssh ubuntu@node-name or ip

2) install juju and bootstrap it then run

  `juju ssh machine-id`

or 

 
  `juju ssh ubuntu@node-name or ip`

Comment: I also found out I can ssh into any box provided the keys were in maas before I deployed. For ubuntu it is `ssh ubuntu@box_name.maas`